# How to complete use of draw tool (and hence complete drawing a line)

Tags: adobe-acrobat

I want to underline the word "manufacture" in a PDF.

I press "D", then left-click mouse under the start of the word to start drawing, then try to left-click again at the end of the word to stop. Unfortunately this doesn't work.

(I've also tried double-click, "Esc", "Enter", all don't work.)

[image]

Using Adobe Acrobat Pro DC 2020.012.20041

Comment: Its usually right mouse button to stop drawing.

Comment: @LPChip: Unfortunately no that doesn't work. Right mouse click brings up a popup with one option: "Cancel".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was incorrectly selecting either the "Polygon" or "Connected Lines" tool.

Select the "Line" tool, then releasing the left-click button will complete the drawing of the line.

(Shift + D = keyboard shortcut to cycle through the "Drawing Tools".)

[image]